# Split pattern code in java

Tags: java

```
((-27.600121, 151.90294900000004), (-27.535655, 151.978654))
```

I have above mentioned value in string form.

I am trying to split and put the value in 4 double variable. See code below.

```
double swLatitude  = 0.0;
 double swLongitude = 0.0;
 double neLatitude  = 0.0;
 double neLongitude = 0.0;

 String tokens[] = school.getBounds().split("(?:,\\s*)+");

System.out.println("get tokens length===>" + tokens.length);

        if (tokens.length != 4)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Expected 4 values in bbox string but found %d: %s\n",
                tokens.length, school.getBounds()));
        }

        swLatitude =  Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
        swLongitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
        neLatitude =  Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
        neLongitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
```

The token length is coming as two instead of 4. Can some one help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not simply, `test.replaceAll("[()]", "").split("[,\\s]+");`

Comment: `spit` part works fine for me. Make sure that `school.getBounds()` returns `((-27.600121, 151.90294900000004), (-27.535655, 151.978654))`. You will also get problems with parsing `(` and `)`. Consider removing them from your string before splitting, as @HovercraftFullOfEels showed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, it's easier to use a Matcher for such a task. It just gets all double values from any String in order they appears in it. Here is some short example. Sure, you may have to add some additional assertion checks:

```
double swLatitude = 0.0;
double swLongitude = 0.0;
double neLatitude = 0.0;
double neLongitude = 0.0;

String tokens[] = new String[4];

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([-?\\d.]+)").matcher(school.getBounds());

int i = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    tokens[i] = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
    i++;
}

if (i != 4) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            String.format("Expected 4 values in bbox string but found %d: %s\n",
                    tokens.length, school.getBounds()));
}

swLatitude =  Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
swLongitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
neLatitude =  Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
neLongitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get help from http://txt2re.com/ that it is a useful site for match patterns.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="((-27.600121, 151.90294900000004), (-27.535655, 151.978654))";

    String re1=".*?";   
    String re2="([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";  // Float 1
    String re3=".*?";   
    String re4="([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";  // Float 2
    String re5=".*?";   
    String re6="([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";  // Float 3
    String re7=".*?";   
    String re8="([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";  // Float 4

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String float1=m.group(1);
        String float2=m.group(2);
        String float3=m.group(3);
        String float4=m.group(4);
        System.out.print("("+float1.toString()+")"+"("+float2.toString()+")"+"("+float3.toString()+")"+"("+float4.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is for you need to make so much String Objects and the also concatenate them into one to get a Pattern, if a Matcher can use a single one regexp to find all it's occurrences and traverse them over?